# I am making a website in angularjs and using ngRoutes. My query is about removing # fromt the url

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

```
Following is my code where I am configuring my routes:

/**
 * Main AngularJS Web Application
 */
var app = angular.module('chocomelte', [
  'ngRoute'
]);

/**
 * Configure the Routes
 */
app
.controller('HomeCtrl',HomeCtrl)
.controller('AboutCtrl',AboutCtrl)
.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "partials/home.html",
        controller: "HomeCtrl"
    })
    .when("/about", {
        templateUrl: "partials/about.html", 
        controller: "AboutCtrl"
    })
}]);
```

This removes # from my url. When I try to go to the /about route by clicking on a button in my UI, it works fine. But when I manually try to type the URL and go to it or refresh the page on /about url, I get this error:
500 internal server error. 
I am not using node in the backend. A simple website using angular in the frontend. How to I configure this on the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Apache server. Finally fixed it. Had to rewrite the urls in the .htaccess file as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

Had to specify index.html as the entry point.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you're setting the base url with this meta tag:

```
<base href="/my-base">
```

Also, you may have to implement URL rewriting on your server when using html5 mode, to make sure that any requests are redirected to the root of your application instead of being interpreted as GET requests.

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location):

> Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application

Comment: I have used the <base href="/my-base"> meta tag. But can you tell me how to rewrite on the server? Not using node.

Comment: What server are you using?